# EntityFramework Database First -- automatically set StoreGeneratedPattern value

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework context that is generated Database-first. I'm adding a table with a GUID PK that will be generated by the database. When I generate the EDMX model from the database, it sets StoreGeneratedPattern to 'None'.

I need to manually change StoreGeneratedPattern to 'Identity' for the application to let the database create the ID's.

Is there a way to ensure that EDMX automatically sets this value correctly?

Comment: `uniqueidentifier` columns can't have an identity specification, so you can't expect EF to know when to set it as identity.

Comment: I see that EF Core handles this better. It detects default constraints in SQL Server and creates the EF model accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **Entity Framework 6** it's just the way it is. When `uniqueidentifier` columns are primary key and have a default value, the EDMX generator tool doesn't mark them as `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`. In a strict sense that's right, because the column doesn't have (can't have) an identity specification.

So in the EDMX designer you have to set the `StoreGeneratedPattern` property of the Id column(s) to `Identity` manually. The good new is that this survives model updates.

The net effect for EF is similar to a true (= numeric) identity column. Whether or not an explicit value is assigned to the Id column:

- The column is ignored in `INSERT` statements
- The generated value is read into the entity during `SaveChanges`.

As indicated by your comment, **Entity Framework-core** (current version 2.0.0) handles this differently. When a model is generated from a database (package manager console: `Scaffold-DbContext`), you'll see an entry in the context's `OnModelCreating` override looking like this:

```cs
entity.Property(e => e.Id)
    .HasColumnName("ID")
    .HasDefaultValueSql("(newsequentialid())");
```

But the behavior is subtly different than in EF6. When no value is set for the Id column (i.e. it is a default `Guid`) the behavior is still the same:

- The column is ignored in the `INSERT` statement
- The generated value is read into the entity during `SaveChanges`.

However, when the `Id` column is set to another value than the default:

- The column is part of the `INSERT` statement
- There is no generated value.

That means that, other than in EF6, as a developer you have to take care that no explicit values are assigned to `Guid` PK properties if you want them to be always generated by the database.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. EF Core is the more complete solution in my mind. Will likely give that a try.

Comment: Bear in mind that EF-core isn't as mature as EF6 yet, although it's [catchinp up](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/Roadmap).

Comment: Yes, thanks. Need to determine if the lack of maturity is acceptable for our application.